# check duplicate rows on condition in datatable using linq

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, datatable

I have a `datatable`. it has 5 columns say (Type, A1, A2, B1, B2)
If Type is A, I want to make sure no 2 rows will have same data in A1 and A2 columns and
for Type B, no 2 rows will have same data in B1 and B2 columns
e.g.

`Type | A1  | A2 | B1 | B2 |
    --------------------------
1   A    | 123 | XY |    |    | 
2   A    | 123 | XY |    |    |
3   B    |     |    | TT | LL |
4   A    | 456 | YZ |    |    |
5   B    |     |    | TT | LL | 
6   A    | 123 | YZ |    |    |
7   B    |     |    | TT | LL |
8   A    | 456 | YZ |    |    |`

In this case I want to flag an error on rows 1,2,4,8
and another error on rows 3,5,7.

Row 6 is OK.

To start with I have done Group by on Key= Type as:

```
var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r["Type"]).ToList();
```

I am not sure if I further use for-each on each group or is there a better way in linq.
Please guide.
Thanks.

Comment: _"I want to flag an error"_ do you want to remove the duplicates or what do you want?

Comment: I want to set `RowError` to that row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous type for the `GroupBy`:

```
var dupGroups = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new{ 
        Row = r,
        IsA = r.Field<string>("Type")=="A",
        IsB = r.Field<string>("Type")=="B",
        A1 = r.Field<string>("A1"),
        A2 = r.Field<string>("A2"),
        B1 = r.Field<string>("B1"),
        B2 = r.Field<string>("B2"),
    })
    .GroupBy(x => x.IsA ? new { Val1 = x.A1, Val2 = x.A2 } : new { Val1 = x.B1, Val2 = x.B2 })
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);

foreach (var dupGroup in dupGroups)
    foreach (DataRow row in dupGroup.Select(x => x.Row))
        row.RowError = "Duplicate detected";
```

Result:

```
DataTable errors = table.GetErrors().CopyToDataTable();
```

---

```
1   A   123     XY      
2   A   123     XY      
3   B               TT      LL
4   A   456     YZ      
5   B               TT      LL
7   B               TT      LL
8   A   456     YZ
```

As you can see, row 6 is not part of the error-table because it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts but it is giving me error as `Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'AnonymousType#1' and 'AnonymousType#2'` for conditional operator(?:) at second new keyword.

Comment: @parixit: i have tested it with your sample data. It is the same anonymous type because both have the same properties `Val1` and `Val2`.  Are you also on .NET 4 or even higher?